# Issue with Hive Data types

Tags: sql, types, hive, hiveql, biginteger

**We have 3 columns from source , colA is of 3 digits, colB is of 5 digits and ColC is of 5 digits.
We need to create 13 digit unique id based on above 3 columns**

```
Query used - select colA*1000000000000 + colC*100000 + colC
Example - 

hive> select 123*1000000000000 + 12345*100000 + 12345;
OK
123001234512345 -- Not Expected
Time taken: 0.091 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

On checking further, below hive query does not give me the correct results.

```
hive> !hive --version;
Hive 2.3.3-mapr-1904-r9
Git git://738a1fde0d37/root/opensource/mapr-hive-2.3/dl/mapr-hive-2.3 -r 265b539b942d0b9f4811b15880204dec5c0c7e1b
Compiled by root on Tue Aug 6 05:36:17 PDT 2019
From source with checksum 88f44b7532ffd7141c15cb5742e9cb51
hive> select cast(12345*1000000 as bigint);
OK
-539901888
Time taken: 0.126 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(12345*10000000 as bigint);
OK
-1104051584
Time taken: 0.02 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(12345*100000000 as bigint);
OK
1844386048
Time taken: 0.018 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(12345*1000000000 as bigint);
OK
1263991296
Time taken: 0.032 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Whereas the below query works -

```
hive> select cast(12345*10000000000 as bigint);
OK
123450000000000
Time taken: 0.017 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(12345*1000 as bigint);
OK
12345000
Time taken: 0.025 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(12345*10000 as bigint);
OK
123450000
Time taken: 0.035 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(12345*100000 as bigint);
OK
1234500000
Time taken: 0.247 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Literals) explains:

> Integral literals are assumed to be INT by default, unless the number exceeds the range of INT in which case it is interpreted as a BIGINT, or if one of the following postfixes is present on the number.

In this expression:

```
cast(12345*1000000 as bigint)
```

The result of `12345*1000000` is cast as a `bigint`.  That does not mean the multiplication is done using that type.  For that, you need to cast *before* multiplying:

```
12345 * cast(1000000 as bigint)
```

Or, you can use the suffixes:

```
12345L * 1000000L
```

Note that no explicit `cast()` is required because the values are already `bigint`.